# Fire .click event on option element nested inside Datalist element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to fire off the .click event when I select an option element from the datalist but can't seem to get it working. I am receiving
 the data to population the datalist from my database.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$("#phone_no").`enter code here`keyup(function(){
    if($("#phone_no").val().length > 2){
        $.get('<?php echo base_url('call_log/search_phone_number/');?>', {phone_no: $(this).val()}, function(data){
            $("datalist").empty();
            $("datalist").html(data);
                if($("datalist").html(data)){
                    $('myCompanies').click(function(){ 
                        alert("hello world");
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

    <input type="text" list="myCompanies" name="phone_no" id="phone_no"><label></label><div id="ss"></div><aside class="clear"></aside><label></label>
```

Comment: What is purpose of attaching `click` event at each `keyup` event? What is `data`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('myCompanies')
```

is looking for a tag named "myCompanies". Assuming you want the click even to fire on the input element, try using

```
$("[list=myCompanies"])
```

instead.